# How to get jquery object for replaced DOM element

Tags: jquery, html

I want to write a plugin that call replaceWith on this, how can I select that new content so I can chain my plugin for new content.

```
$.fn.spam = function() {
    this.replaceWith('<span>spam</span>');
};
```

and I want to do something like

```
$('div').span().css('background-color', 'red');
```

`replaceWith` return old content, how can I get the new content?

Comment: save this in a var and return it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.fn.spam = function() {
    var elems = $();
    this.each(function() {
        var span = $('<span />', {text: 'spam'});
        $(this).replaceWith(span);
        elems.push(span.get(0));
    });
    return $(elems);
};

$('div').spam().css('background-color', 'red');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3dLxs/)

Comment: I guess the CSS is not part of what he wants in the plugin.

Comment: @Broxzier - Ah, get it now ?

Comment: You can do this in one line using `elems.push($('<span />', {text: 'spam'}).replaceAll($(this))[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

maybe like this :

```
$.fn.span = function() {
var theNewElt = $('<span>spam</span>');
this.replaceWith(theNewElt);
return theNewElt;
};


$('div').span().css('background-color', 'red');
```

Test it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQcPm/)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this in one line using `replaceAll` jquery method

```
$.fn.spam = function() {
    return $('<span>spam</span>').replaceAll(this);
};
```